# How to solve classic ODE $x'' = a^2x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x'' = a^2x$$

How to solve that ODE? (I know that the solution is $x = A \cdot \sin at + B \cdot \cos at$)

Comment: Did you miss something? If $x = A\sin{at} + B \cos{at}$ then $x'' = -a^2x$

Comment: I am trying to understand the solution to my other question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467035/periodic-solutions-of-second-order-ode-with-matrix/4467089#4467089

Answer (score 1):

For homogeneous linear differential equations one typically introduces an ansatz of the form $x(t) = e^{\lambda t}$. Differentiating this expression, one gets $x''(t) = \lambda^2 e^{\lambda t}$ and thus $\lambda^2 = a^2$. Hence $\lambda = \pm a$ and we find solutions $e^{at}$ and $e^{-at}$. The general solution is a linear combination of these two terms, so
$$x(t) = Ae^{at}+Be^{-at}.$$

Now, if your equation was instead $x''=-a^2x$, then you would find that $\lambda^2=-a^2$ in our ansatz, meaning $\lambda=\pm ia$. On the other hand, we have the Euler identity $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta+i\sin\theta$. It is a fact that if a complex-valued expression satisfies a linear ODE with only real coefficients, then both the real and imaginary parts of this complex-valued function satisfy the ODE. Thus $\cos(at)$ and $\sin(at)$ would be solutions in this case, and the general solution to $x''=-a^2x$ would have the form $x(t) = A\cos at+B\sin at$.

Comment: Thank you sir! I'm new to that world and doing my best to understand ODEs.

Comment: I see. Well, for the sake of pedagogy, there is one last case I didn't treat in my answer: what do you think the solution ought to look like if the $\lambda$ equation obtained from the ansatz (sometimes called the characteristic equation) has $\lambda = a\pm bi$?

Comment: @4plus4man another elucidating exercise is to consider the case when $\lambda^2 = 0$ and what solutions would satisfy the ODE $x'' = 0$. Although seemingly trivial, it helps understand how to obtain independent solutions when the characteristic equation has roots with multiplicity 2

Answer (score 0):

You can also proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
x'' = a^{2}x & \Longleftrightarrow x'' - a^{2}x = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x'' - ax') + (ax' - a^{2}x) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x' - ax)' + a(x' - ax) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow u' + au = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\exp(at)u)' = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \exp(at)u = b\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x' - ax = b\exp(-at)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\exp(-at)x)' = b\exp(-2at)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x(t) = B\exp(-at) + C\exp(at)
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

**BONUS**

You can also try to multiply both sides by $x'$.